# I am trying to get physical address using latitude and longitude in Android

Tags: java, android, maps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get physical address using latitude and longitude in Android

Everything is working fine but for some coordinates (like this one: 32.696627 , 74.8798822) does not work and my App crashes.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import static infolabs.localite.R.id.longitude;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String s ="";
    EditText lati , longi;
    TextView t;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    public void show_me_the_details(View v) throws Exception
    {

        lati  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longi  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        double a  = Double.parseDouble(lati.getText().toString());
        double b  = Double.parseDouble(longi.getText().toString());


        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());


        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(a, b, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details);

        String full_address = address+"\n"+city+"\n"+state+"\n"+country+"\n"+postalCode+"\n"+knownName+"\n";
        t.setText(full_address);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Specifically: **crashes** is not a description we could help with much.

Comment: In my opinion you must try performing the reverse geocoding in a Separate Thread. Do give a cross check for Permissions in Manifest and try to post the exception dump.

Answer (score 0):

Andriod's geocoder API are free and will give u correct address.

As per crashing is concerned you need to debug it.Try to put Logging and enclose the code In try catch.

Observation : I have  observed that the geocoder code which u wrote is in UI thread which is not the way it should be calculated in background service there will be cases where the program will hang if the API takes lot of time.

Try to go through the Andriod standard practice as geocoder is most popular API.